# Keras save checkpoints

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am following [this blog](http://machinelearningmastery.com/check-point-deep-learning-models-keras/) and I am having trouble to implement saving checkpoints as it's used in linked blog. At line 23 it used:

`filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.hdf5"`.

So I tried to tweak the code a little bit to be more dynamic:

`filepath = '{0}/checkpoints/checkpoint-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5'.format(directory)`.

Where I want to store all checkpoints of given architecture in 1 directory, e.g.: `./architecture1/checkpoints/`

But I get the following error: `KeyError: 'epoch'`. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S.: `filepath = "./checkpoints/checkpoint-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"` works, but it saves all checkpoints in 1 directory which I don't want.

Comment: did you try import os; filepath = os.path.join(directory, 'checkpoints', 'checkpoint-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5')  ?

Comment: How do you assign a directory to a model?

Comment: Actually I just found out that this problem can be fixed with simple string concatenation.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future users and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: I understand, but I am not eligable to anwser my own question for 48 hours. In the mean time I hope to get an anwser regarding `.format()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `format`, the proper way is to escape the brackets like this:

```
filepath = '{0}/checkpoints/checkpoint-{{epoch:02d}}-{{val_loss:.2f}}.hdf5'.format(directory)
```

So if `directory = 'weights'`, `filepath` would be `'weights/checkpoints/checkpoint-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5'`.

(Take care if `directory` contains `{}`)

Comment: @narn I posted that as my second solution, you said it didnt work :/

Comment: i guess you know what tou are talking about, but can you point out the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `format` on a `format` eligible string but supply only one of the keys - and that causes an error.

What you are doing is

```
"{0} some text here {epoch:02d}".format("text")
```

and that is causing an error, because it looks for the second key and can't find it.

If you want your code to be dynamic, what I would do is:

```
"{0}".format(directory) + "/checkpoints/checkpoint-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"
```

Comment: Actually 2nd example does not work, it still gives `KeyError: 'epoch'` error. 1st example works though.

Comment: really? surprising, thanks for the feedback i'll edit it